# Str_extract not working

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to extract the first time stamp from the following character:

"WHENSEPTEMBER 14, 2015 @ 11:56 AM - 12:00 PM EDT"

I have a whole list of them and they are vectors, as required.

```
> is.vector(data$description)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(data$info)
[1] TRUE

>str_extract(data$info, "\\@ [0-9]+:[0-9]{2}")
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
```

I realize that my regex is not entirely correct yet to extract only the first time.  But at this point it won't extract anything.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output dput(data), because I get "@ 11:56" when I try this.

Comment: Listen to the feedback and provide dput(data) or str(data). If you read carefully about is.vector I think you will realize that it is misleading you.

Comment: `str` is a good friend who reveals much.  Have you `str`-ed `data`?

Comment: Could you post the `str()` of your data, as already requested twice?

Comment: Without a reproducible example this is not solvable.  I voted to close.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback.  Sorry I was not able to reply sooner, but your instructions guided me in the right direction and I was able to resolve my problem!  You were right is.vector is misleading.  Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly clear whether we need only the 'HH:MM' part or need the `AM/PM` as well.  If this is only to extract the 'HH:MM' after the `@` followed by a space, we can use regex lookarounds (`(?<=\\@ )`) to match the numbers followed by `:` followed by two digits.  Also, specify the `regex` or `fixed`.

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract(v1,  regex="(?<=\\@ )[0-9]+:[0-9]{2}")
#[1] "11:56"
```

Or using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, "(?<=\\@ )[0-9]+:[0-9]{2}")
#[1] "11:56"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "WHENSEPTEMBER 14, 2015 @ 11:56 AM - 12:00 PM EDT"
```

Comment: you are using the stringi package whereas I am using stringr package.  Nevertheless, this does not work when I use your regex.  I am not worried about the regex, I am worried about the fact that the function isn't working at all and returning me the error shown in the question

Comment: @user3859248 Sorry, i got mistaken.  But, `stringr` is a wrapper for `string`i`.  BTW, if you are using `stringr`, you don't need to specify the `regex=`.  It works for me.

Comment: @user3859248  BTW, I am using `stringr_1.0.0` on `R 3.2.2.`

Comment: Thank you, yes so I figured the problem would persist anyway, it seems like I did not really have a vector, as I thought I did.  Thank you for your help, your regex extracted exactly what I wanted and it works now, thank you!

Comment: @user3859248  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Something seems to be wrong with your data vector. The functions works as it should on the string you provided:

```
x <- "WHENSEPTEMBER 14, 2015 @ 11:56 AM - 12:00 PM EDT"
x
[1] "WHENSEPTEMBER 14, 2015 @ 11:56 AM - 12:00 PM EDT"
str_extract(x, "\\@ [0-9]+:[0-9]{2}")
[1] "@ 11:56"
```